# Obtain subnet ID from a vNet

Tags: azure, terraform

I have created a virtual network with 3 subnets within the vNet resource block and I was wondering how do I get the ID of the subnet? I know if I created them separately using azurerm_subnet and then use that in the output, but when the subnets are created inline with the vnet I am unsure?

**main.tf**

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet" {
    name = var.vnet.name
    resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.id
    location = azurerm_resource_group.rg.id
    address_space = var.vnet.address_space
    dns_servers = var.vnet.dns_servers

    subnet {
        name = var.subnet.key_vault.name
        address_prefix = var.subnet.key_vault.address_prefix
    }

    subnet {
        name = var.subnet.storage_account.name
        address_prefix = var.subnet.storage_account.address_prefix
    }

    subnet {
        name = var.subnet.hostpool1.name
        address_prefix = var.subnet.hostpool1.address_prefix
    }
}
```

**output.tf**

```
output "subnet_id" {
    value = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.subnet[*].id
}
```

**error message**

```
│ Error: Incorrect attribute value type
│ 
│   on session_hosts/main.tf line 31, in resource "azurerm_network_interface" "avd_nic":
│   31:       subnet_id = var.subnet_id
│     ├────────────────
│     │ var.subnet_id is list of string with 3 elements
│ 
│ Inappropriate value for attribute "subnet_id": string required.
```

Comment: Try with, e.g., `azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.subnet[*].id`

Comment: @MarkoE, I have tried what you've suggested, and I get a new error (I've updated my question with the new code and error). I assume I must change the [*] to something, but I'm not sure what I need to change it to?

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce , to output subnet id’s and got the output with below code:***

```
data "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "xxxxx"  
 //location = "westus2"
}
```

***variable.tf***

```
variable "Subnetlist" {
 type = list
  default = [
    {
      ip      = "10.0.1.0/24"
      name     = "subnet-1"
    },
    {
      ip      = "10.0.2.0/24"
      name     = "subnet-2"
    }
   ]
}
```

main.tf

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet" {
    name = "ka-vnetwk"
    resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
    location = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
    address_space = var.vnet.address_space
    dns_servers = var.vnet.dns_servers
 }
  


resource "azurerm_subnet" "SUBNETS" {
#for_each = var.Subnetlist
 for_each                  ={for idx, val in var.Subnetlist: idx => val}
name = each.value.name
address_prefixes=[each.value.ip]
  resource_group_name  = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name
}

output "subnet_ids" {
   value = values(azurerm_subnet.SUBNETS)[*].id
}
```

Please try looping below way with small corrections for inline subnets .

- Loop through the values of the list like >    `value = values(azurerm_subnet.SUBNETS)[*].id`
- ***`And resource must be output  “subnet_ids “ and not subnet_id`***

---

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but this won't resolve my issue, because I have setup the subnets within the VNET resource block, whereas you've separated them to using a SUBNET resource block which is what I am trying to avoid reducing the amount of code I am writing. Keeping them in the VNET resource block but pulling out a single subnet ID out of the three I am creating is what I am after, is that possible?